# Splitting a list entry in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv

I am importing a CSV file into a list in Python. When I split it into list elements then print a index,the entry is printed like this.

`2000-01-03,3.745536,4.017857,3.631696,3.997768,2.695920,133949200`

How would I split this list so if I wanted to just print a solo element like this? 
`2000-01-03`Here is my code so far.

```py
def main():
    list = []
    filename = "AAPL.csv"
    with open(filename) as x:
        for line in x.readlines():
            val = line.strip('\n').split(',')
            list.append(val)
    print(list[2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code build a list of lists, precisely a list (of rows) of lists (of fields).

To extract one single element, say first field of third row, you could do:

```
...
print(list[2][0])
```

But except for trivial tasks, you should use the csv module when processing csv file, because it is robust to corner cases like newlines or field separarors contained in fields. Your code could become:

```
def main():
    list = []
    filename = "AAPL.csv"
    with open(filename) as x:
        rd = csv.reader(x)
        for val in rd:          # the reader is an iterator of lists of fields
            list.append(val)
    print(list[2][0])
```